# How to find classname starting with a particular text and ending with a particular text through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

Below is the element and I need to find the class names matching with the first **`css-`** and ending with **`widget`**, How do i find it in selenium (java)?

Tried with the below code, but it didnt work

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[starts-with(@class, 'css-')]"));
List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[contains(@class, 'css-')]"));
List<WebElement> list3 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[ends-with(@class, 'widget')]"));
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Post your error messages or explain how it didn't achieve what you wanted. Is there an actual `BODY` HTML tag that hold these partial class names or is it some other HTML tag? If you are looking for any tag, swap `*` for `BODY`, e.g. `//*[starts-with(@class, 'css-')]`.

Answer (score 4):

I use CSS selectors, to find any element of any type:

`driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("[class^='css-'][class$='widget']"))`

Where we find any element, which has a `class` attribute using [], that begins with `^=` and ends with `$=`

To find a div:

`driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("div[class^='css-'][class$='widget']"))`

Answer (score 1):

@elworthy's answer was in the right direction about the *CssSelector* which you can use and as per your code trials the following should work:

```
List<WebElement> list3 = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("//body[class^='css-'][class$='widget']"));
```

However if you want to construct a *xpath* it is worth to mention *Selenium* supports **xpath v1.0** and `ends-with()` is part of **xpath v2.0**. So the equivalent *xpath* will be:

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[starts-with(@class, 'css-') and contains(@class, 'widget')]"));
```